# How to grouping list by value and put in new dynamic variable using Python

Tags: python, list, data-science, data-analysis

How to grouping list by value and put in new dynamic variable using Python.
I have some data list like this and i want to store in new dynamic variable list based on value K93, K94, K0JA => (this will be a dynamic value)

```
data_list = [
(('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K94', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [600, 30]),
(('K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJNBK', 0.0, 800.0, 400), [300.0, 15]),
(('K94', 'AMK2FJNBK', 0.0, 800.0, 400), [300.0, 15])]
```

i want result like this:

```
list_K93 = [
(('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K93', 'AMK2FJNBK', 0.0, 800.0, 400), [300.0, 15]),
]

list_K94 = [
(('K94', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
(('K94', 'AMK2FJNBK', 0.0, 800.0, 400), [300.0, 15])
]

list_K0JA = [
(('K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [600, 30]),
(('K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [300, 15])
]
```

Comment: why do you want to create a dynamic variable? That isn't possible in general (outside of hacking the interpreter internals) and it is almost never the right approach. use a *dictionary* to group by some key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of dynamically named variables, you should create a dict with the desired keys instead, which can be done by initializing each new key of the output dict with a list and appending each tuple entry to the list:

```
data_dict = {}
for t in data_list:
    data_dict.setdefault(t[0][0], []).append(t)
```

`data_dict` becomes:

```
{
     'K93': [(('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
             (('K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
             (('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
             (('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
             (('K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
             (('K93', 'AMK2FJNBK', 0.0, 800.0, 400), [300.0, 15])],
     'K94': [(('K94', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
             (('K94', 'AMK2FJNBK', 0.0, 800.0, 400), [300.0, 15])],
     'K0JA': [(('K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [600, 30]),
              (('K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [300, 15])]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cluster data via a dictionary like this:

```
result = {}
for i in data_list:
    if i[0][0] in result:
        result[i[0][0]].append(i)
    else:
        result[i[0][0]] = []
        result[i[0][0]].append(i)
```

So that the result would be a dictionary like this:

```
{'K93': [(('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
         (('K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
         (('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
         (('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
         (('K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
         (('K93', 'AMK2FJNBK', 0.0, 800.0, 400), [300.0, 15])],
 'K94': [(('K94', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
         (('K94', 'AMK2FJNBK', 0.0, 800.0, 400), [300.0, 15])],
 'K0JA': [(('K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [600, 30]),
         (('K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [300, 15])]}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic variable like this

```
i = "test"
globals()[f"dynamic_variable_{i}"] = i
print(dynamic_variable_test)
```

Here is the code

```
 data_list = [
   (('K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),
   (('K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),]
   
def create_dynamic_var(name,value):
  globals()[f"list_{name}"] = []
  globals()[f"list_{name}"].append(value)

  
for elem in data_list:
     print(elem[0][0])
     create_dynamic_var(elem[0][0],elem)
     
print(list_K93)
```